# Multiple object request using Volley Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to call API Using Volley. There is an Multiple object Request So i don't Know Proper way. I was tried to code as below.But it does not give me Response.So can Anyone help me???

**MainActivity**

```
public void  getJsonResponsePost(){

    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    /*{"data":{"lang_type":"1","keyword":"","latitude":23.022499999999997,"longitude":72.57139833333333,"category":6}}*/
    try {
        jsonData.put("data",json);
        json.put("lang_type","1");
        json.put("keyword","");
        json.put("latitude",23.022499999999997);
        json.put("longitude",72.57139833333333);
        json.put("category",6);
        Log.d("TAG",jsonData.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
                    Log.d("String Response :",response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(" Error getting  :",error.toString());
        }
    });

    jsonObjectRequest.setTag(REQ_TAG);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

I get the following response

```
String Response :: {"status":"0","message":"Please pass the language type."}
```

Comment: post you api code here

Comment: is there any mistake in my code?? can you plz explain?

Comment: `lang_type` look at this node is it same that your api asking..

Comment: yes.. i already check this in POSTMAN too. it's perfect

Comment: `Log.d("TAG",jsonData.toString());` what is log here?

Comment: {"data":{"lang_type":"1","keyword":"","latitude":23.022499999999997,"longitude":72.57139833333333,"category":6}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160696/discussion-between-chitra-nandpal-and-abhishek-singh).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
    try {
    json.put("lang_type","1");
    json.put("keyword","");
    json.put("latitude",23.022499999999997);
    json.put("longitude",72.57139833333333);
    json.put("category",6);
    jsonData.put("data",json);
    Log.d("TAG",jsonData.toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonData, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
            {
                Log.d("String Response :",response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d(" Error getting  :",error.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! i was solved the issue.my mistake is i am passing json insted of jsonData